# generate sql reports by time interval: hour

Tags: mysql, report, date-format

I read an article about generating reports by a time interval of a day/month/year (http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

As example, with this sql I can report gross monthly sales:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sales_time, '%Y-%m-01')) AS month_beginning,
       SUM(gross) AS total,
       COUNT(*) AS transactions
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sales_time, '%Y-%m-01'))
 ORDER BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(sales_time, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

But I cannot create a sql-report **by hour**...

This is not working... :(

```
DATE_FORMAT(sales_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') // not working...
```

How can I make a query that generates a report by hour?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you repeat the expression everywhere.  However, in MySQL, you can use column aliases in `group by` (as well as `order by`), so you can just do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sales_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS byhour,
       SUM(gross) AS total,
       COUNT(*) AS transactions
FROM sales
GROUP BY byhour
ORDER BY byhour;
```

The problem with your expression is likely to be `date()` -- it will remove the time component from the expression.